# Baking normal map from multiple materials into one texture problem

Tags: texturing, normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I have a problem with normal map baking. I have a lot of objects on scene and they have different materials with base color, normal map, roughness etc.(all maps made in substance designer) And I want to bake all these normal maps into one texture. I did it some time ago with different project and it work good but now something is wrong and normal map on new texture look ugly and have weird colors.
I have no idea what is wrong. I checked face orientation, double faces, scale, rotation of the objects and still not work.

I did the same things with base colors and it baked into one texture pretty well so I don’t know what is wrong with normal map here

I’m new here and I hope my screenshoot have been added here to my post

please help

[image]

Comment: You may want to check how you exported your normal maps from Substance Designer. If you exported them in the DirectX format, it may be the reason for this. Blender uses OpenGL normal format. The difference between the two is that the Y channel (represented by the green color) is flipped from one another.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka I think you were right. I return to substance designer, invert green color on normals and change color space in blender nodes to 'raw' and it works! I would never have thought about it honestly. Thank you so much for help! You have saved my project!! Thank you!!!
Have a nice day! :)

Comment: I'm glad that I could help.